# Finish all previous activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen

My application  has the following flow screens :

`Home->screen 1->screen 2->screen 3->screen 4->screen 5`

Now I have a common `log out`  button in each screens

(`Home/ screen 1 / screen 2 /screen 3/ screen 4 / screen 5`)

I want that when user clicks on the log out button(from any screen), all the screens will be finished and a new screen `Log in` will open .

I have tried nearly all `FLAG_ACTIVITY` to achieve this.
I also go through some answers in stackoverflow, but not being able to solve the problem.
My application is on Android 1.6 so not being able to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Is there any way to solve the issue ?

Comment: Do you run your nested activities using startActivityForResult?

Comment: no.All the activities are started with startActivity.

Comment: I am using nested activities while cod runs finishaffinitytask() in nested activity. does it change the behaviour? as sometimes i am getting Failure delivering result ResultInfo when finishaffinitytask runs.

Comment: Please check this answer, It will surely help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25159180/2732632

Comment: Android 21 introduced Activity.finishAndRemoveTask().

Comment: Only with this flags  work for  me:  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Answer (score 604, accepted):

Use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear all the activities on top of home.

Assuming you are finishing the login screen when the user logs in and home is created and afterward all the screens from 1 to 5 on top of that one. The code I posted will return you to home screen finishing all the other activities. You can add an extra in the intent and read that in the home screen activity and finish it also (maybe launch login screen again from there or something).

I am not sure but you can also try going to login with this flag. I don't know how the activities will be ordered in that case. So don't know if it will clear the ones below the screen you are on including the one you are currently on but it's definitely the way to go.

Comment: User is showing his first screen as home screen,thats the main issue.

Comment: well as i have it my response you need to get back to the home screen and finish that one. so the process call the intent above from any screen. receive the intent on the Home screen and instantly lauch a intent towards login and finish home after the startActivity method. you can also override the pending animation to null for in and out so that it doesn't show the transition ( i do that because it feels kinda quicker).so that should be working fine for the thing you need.

Comment: Clear top will work for clearing everything above the activity you are calling with the intent. so this means since activities are stacking above home they will be cleared. its just a matter of starting the login activity afterwards. i have been using it like that and i had no issues with it. also you need to declare the activity to have a single instance so you dont accidently launch another instance of the home activity (which then would be on top and wont clear things below)

Comment: Rather than declare the activity as `singleInstance`, consider using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as the flags for the Intent. This will finish intervening activities and start (or bring back to the foreground) the desired activity.

Comment: Yeah @CommonsWare is right. i didn't think of that. but still as a discussion maybe: why not actually declare the activity singleTop/singleInstance? its the home activity. i don't think there would be a reason at any point to have 2 instances of that one right?

Comment: @DArkO: Few apps need a `singleInstance` activity -- that's mostly for home screens. You can declare `singleTop` if you want; I personally prefer to manage that at the `Intent` level.

Comment: @ CommonsWare  Adding `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` to my activity did not help me.It did not finish the intervening  activities.When I press back from the Login screen I can see the previous activities.Here is my code `Intent  intent=new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Login.class);intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok that seems reasonable. but from my experience singleTop solves some cases where you forget to add the Single top flag and also when working in a team than its more of a coding convention whether to use the flag or the manifest declaration. nvm lets get back to this question. @Tanmay Mandal you shouldnt launch the login activity because it will launch it on top of the others since it is created from scratch when you call the intent. what i said was to actually launch the home activity and from it launch the Login and finish the home. that will clear the Top activities.

Comment: @DArkO I think thats the solution I need to implement.calling the home and then finish it and call the login.let me try it.

Comment: This is great one, for which I am searching. This code will be always useful for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It still keep open current activity, getActivity().finishAffinity() worled in my case.

Comment: No it wont keep the current activity alive, in your case this means that your old activity doesn't exist and a new one is opened on top instead of going back down through the stack.

Comment: this code only clear the top activity stack, for clearing all activities

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: Not sure this is acceptable as it relaunches an activity again iinstead of just removing and finishing all activities

Comment: For me it wasn't working initially because i was doing 'setFlags' instead of 'addFlags'.

Answer (score 342):

You may try `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. It will totally clears all previous activity(s) and start new activity.

Comment: The proper solution, but only API 11+

Comment: I ended up using this extra flag as it doesn't cause a delay when showing the main activity (it won't restart it so it's much faster).

Comment: @riwnodennyk why API 11+?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar cause it looks like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK was introduced only in API 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Comment: @riwnodennyk my bad i thought you are talking about `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: Use IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK for pre 11 versions

Comment: I will edit this answer for more convenient solution for newbies.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. Can’t believe it’s not the accepted solution as the current accepted one didn’t work!

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); working for me, thanks!

Comment: @StevenPena i can't get that flag to work for pre-11. is that the only flag you're adding? I'm doing this `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Comment: @ono Yes. That should be all you need. Make sure your target activity's launch mode is set as as "singleTask" in the manifest.

Comment: @StevenPena just not working, even with singleTask. back always takes me to a previous activity

Comment: @ono Not sure then. I'm only using that one flag and that's the only change to the activity I had to make. The only other thing I've set up is that my initial screen has "alwaysRetainTaskState=false" in the manifest. Maybe that'll fix whatever issue you are having.

Comment: @StevenPena ok i think i got it. the solution is to NOT finish the initial activity. missed that somewhere

Comment: @StevenPena but now hitting back the 2nd activity takes you back to the initial instead of closing the app. the struggles.....

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All works without finish() or finishAffinity(), just intent flags.

Answer (score 158):

Before launching your new Activity, simply add the following code:

```
finishAffinity();
```

Or if you want it to work in previous versions of Android:

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
```

Comment: ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this); calls activity.finish() for api < 16. So it won't work.

Comment: @Beto Caldas, I have confirmed the source code myself, it will not work for API < 16 as AamirAbro mentioned. It will just finish the activity that you passing on API < 16.

Comment: This remains the best solution to date for API > 16 as other solutions create a lag when clearing or recreating a task

Answer (score 39):

**When the user wishes to exit all open activities**, they should press a button which loads the first Activity that runs when your application starts, clear all the other activities, then have the last remaining activity finish. Have the following code run when the user presses the exit button. In my case, `LoginActivity` is the first activity in my program to run.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code clears all the activities except for `LoginActivity`. Then put the following code inside the `LoginActivity`'s `onCreate(...)`, to listen for when `LoginActivity` is recreated and the 'EXIT' signal was passed:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();  
}
```

**Why is making an exit button in Android so hard?**

Android tries hard to discourage you from having an "exit" button in your application, because they want the user to never care about whether or not the programs they use are running in the background or not.

The Android OS developers want your program to be able to survive an unexpected shutdown and power off of the phone, and when the user restarts the program, they pick up right where they left off. So the user can receive a phone call while they use your application, and open maps which requires your application to be freed for more resources.

When the user resumes your application, they pick up right where they left off with no interruption. This exit button is usurping power from the activity manager, potentially causing problems with the automatically managed android program life cycle.

Answer (score 37):

I guess I am late but there is simple and short answer.
There is a finishAffinity() method in Activity that will finish the current activity and all parent activities, but it works only in Android 4.1 or higher.

For API 16+, use

`finishAffinity();`

For below 16, use

`ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(YourActivity.this);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice and simple answer

Answer (score 33):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, classObject);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This Will work for all Android versions. Where `IntentCompat` the class added in Android Support library.

Comment: `IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is not recognised, use `Intent` instead of `IntentCompat`.

Answer (score 30):

Use the following for activity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

remove CLEAR_TASK flag for fragment use.

I hope this may use for some people.

Answer (score 24):

On a side note, good to know
This answer works (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468685/7034327)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

whereas this doesn't work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

`.setFlags()` **replaces any previous flags** and doesn't append any new flags while `.addFlags()` does.

So this will also work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Great explanation about the difference between setFlag vs addFlag, thank you

Answer (score 22):

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()):

> ```
> public void finishAffinity ()
> ```
>
> Added in API level 16

Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other activities of the second application, all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the task switch.

Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying to do so.

Answer (score 16):

If your application has minimum sdk version 16 then you can use **finishAffinity()**

Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

This is work for me In Top Payment screen remove all back-stack activits,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
         finishAffinity();
        startActivity(new Intent(PaymentDoneActivity.this,Home.class));
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity%28%29

Answer (score 11):

In my case I use `finishAffinity()` function in last activity like:

```
finishAffinity()
startHomeActivity()
```

Hope it'll be useful.

Answer (score 10):

A solution I implemented for this (I think I found it on Stack Overflow somewhere, but I don't remember, so thanks to whoever did that in the first place):

From any of your activities do this:

```
// Clear your session, remove preferences, etc.
Intent intent  = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your LoginActivity, overwrite onKeyDown:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: That's usually a very bad idea, tho it may work, it introduces a point of contact that may break in the future and it will be hard to debug. I'm telling you from experience :)

Answer (score 10):

For logout button on last screen of app, use this code on logout button listener to finish all open previous activities, and your problem is solved.

```
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, loginScreen.class);
ntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

i have same problem
you can use `IntentCompat` , like this :

```
import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

---

this code work for me .

Android api **17**

Answer (score 8):

```
    Intent i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StartUp_Page.class);
i1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i1);
finish();
```

Comment: why **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** twice?

Comment: From what I understand, .setFlags replaces the previous flags and does not append any flags. .addFlags is what you wanted to use I presume? Cause all the code above i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); gets wiped out

Comment: addFlags Works for me

Comment: `setFlags` will replace all previous, so last `setFlags` is only valid, previous are replaced. So you don't need to call `i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Answer (score 8):

instead of using `finish()` just use `finishAffinity();`

Comment: Good answer but requires API 16

Answer (score 6):

Log in->Home->screen 1->screen 2->screen 3->screen 4->screen 5

on screen 4 (or any other) ->

```
StartActivity(Log in)
```

with

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Comment: When I pressing back button all the previous activities are show in the order they were .those activities need to be closed, when the logout button clicked there will be only one activity in the stack and that will be the login activity.And there is no login screen.User starts from home screen.

Answer (score 6):

for API >= 15 to API 23
simple solution.

```
 Intent nextScreen = new Intent(currentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 nextScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivity(nextScreen);
 ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(currentActivity.this);
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer so that everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `startActivityForResult()` in your previous activities, just override `OnActivityResult()` and call the `finish();` method inside it in all activities.. This will do the job...

Comment: No, I am using `startActivity` only.

Comment: It will be difficult to maintain `onActivityResult` on each activity.I have implemeted DArkO 's suggestion and achieved my goal and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

When user click on the logout button then write the following code:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

And also when after login if you call new activity do not use finish();

Answer (score 3):

I guess I am late but there is simple and short answer. There is a finishAffinity() method in Activity that will finish the current activity and all parent activities, but it works only in Android 4.1 or higher.

For API 16+, use

finishAffinity();

For below 16, use

ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(YourActivity.this);

Hope it helps!

shareedit
answered May 27 '18 at 8:03

Akshay Taru

Answer (score 2):

If you log in the user in `screen 1` and from there you go to the other screens, use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Screen1.class);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When I  pressing back button all the previous activities are show in the order they were .those activities need to be closed, when the logout button clicked there will be only one activity in the stack and that will be the login activity.

Comment: If you want this behavior, you have to override `onKeyDown` and `onBackPressed` (or `onKeyDown`, if you want to support Android versions < 2.0) in each one of your activities (except the login one), and `startActivity(login)` there as shown above.

Comment: I have a button which will take me to the login screen finishing all activities in the stack.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, when you go from the login screen, not when finishing the login screen.

And then in all forward activities, use this for logout:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginScreen.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way, it'll clear all history and exit

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to work on every device despite API level (even for < 11)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best way to close all the previous activities and clear the memory**

```
finishAffinity()
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the flags on my end and still haven't worked. I have an application with a very similar design and I have a possible solution in terms of logic. I have built my Login and Logout using shared preferences.

If I logout, data in my shared preferences is destroyed/deleted.

From any of my activities such as Home.java I check whether shared preferences has data and in this case it won't because I destroyed it when I logged out from one of the screens. Therefore logic destroys/finishes that activity and takes me back to the Login activity. You can replicate this logic in all your other activities.

However remember to perform this check inside onPostResume() because this is what is called when you go back to Home.java

Code Sample Below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("user_details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (pref.getAll().isEmpty()){
        //Shared Preferences has no data.
        //The data has been deleted
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        //Finish destroys that activity which in our case is the Home.java
    }


    super.onPostResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the activity you want to finish then, use broadcast receiver. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379275/2828651) solution describe how to do it.

Comment: You might want to give more details, while leaving a reference is good, link only answers are discouraged

Comment: Assuming that Activity A wants to close activity B, then setup a broadcast receiver in Activity B, and the action will be finish();. when calling from the activity A then if activity B is working it will be killed. otherwise nothing will happen

Answer (score -1):

In **Kotlin** this way:

in Another Activity (with some classes), under `Imports`

```
var activity:Activity?=null
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

Then, under `onCreate`

```
activity=this
```

in MainActivity now:

```
activity?.finish()
```