# I can't stop my progress because of some running thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress

Last week, I asked a question about how to finish my progress entirely,someone tell me to do it like this:

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

but the question is: I try to get `JSONObject` from my server,so I new Thread and use handler to
handle this. but now, I can't finish my progress!!

when I start my app , I can find a new progress in DDMS !!!!!what's wrong??

Comment: Because, If you're using above code. It won't stop your app properly. Its just do like pressing home button from app. So, you've to properly quit your app as per in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11430255/940096) or `user:LalitPoptani`'s answer if you want to close.

Comment: If by progress you mean process, Android does not kill your process entirelly when you close your app.

Comment: Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of thread so you can cancel it when you want..