# finishing all the activities after completing a transaction

Tags: android

I have a set of some activities which co-ordinate with each other to complete some transaction..
After the transaction is complete I am redirected to the first activity again for a new transaction...
what I want is after completing of the transaction..when I am redirected to first activity, the app should close when I press the `back key`, i.e, I don't want to see the previous transaction and it should appear like the application has just started..
What should be done for that???

Also I don't want to `finish()` the activities when the transaction is going on....After the completion of transaction only all the activities from previous transaction should be killed...
And Also `startActivityForResult()` is not going to solve my problem.

Suggest your answers please..

Comment: You can register a BroadCastReceiver and send a broadcast. [Have a look at this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11430509/726863)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you override the `back-button` pressed method and then do whatever you want the app to behave like you want it to . Override the `onBackPressed()` method and if you want the app to start again then create an intent that fires up your first activity or do `finish()` if you want to close the app (but you dont want to do that either)

Answer (score 1):

an Easy way to do that:

in the first activity use public static variables.

and change them from the other activites  mainActivity.VariableName = "whatever"
when you return to the main activity you will have all the data you want.

Comment: this is safe to start another activity without losing your data

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps:

1. Take a static boolean variable in your FirstActivity

   **public static boolean killApplication = false;**
2. Override onBackPressed method in your FirstActivity like

   ```
   public void onBackPressed()
   {
       super.onBackPressed();

       FirstActivity.killApplication = true;

   }
   ```
3. Override onResume method in all Activities like

   ```
    protected void onResume()
    {      
        if (FirstActivity.killApplication) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
   ```
4. set **killApplication = false** in your FirstActivity onCreate() method.