# how to finish all activities except the first activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I google it but even if i run this code below it didnt finish the other activities.

```
ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().ctrl = false;
            UserManager.getInstance().loginControl();
            OrderManager.getInstance().orderCtrl = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(OrderComplete.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i also added the 'android:launchMode="singleTop"' to the manifest

Comment: is it not finishing all the Activities or some Activities ? i think Activities which are still doing work like Running any Thread may be are not finished by this way !

Comment: when i want to go back it some activities still be there

Comment: Are there any Running Thread in That Activities ? or `AsyncTask` etc ?

Comment: That's the Reason Your `AsyncTask` is not Finished i.e Still Doing SOme work in Background which is causing your this code not to finish the  Activity ! i Was ALso FAcing the Same Problem Earlier due to `AysncTask` !

Comment: than,what should i do to finish it !

Comment: check your `AsyncTask` why its not finishing and make sure to finish the thread or use time outs etc !

Comment: Adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK worked for us

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To clear top activities from stack use below code

```
Intent intents = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intents);
finish();
```

It will **delete all activities from stack** either asynctask run or not in the application.

It works fine and also a good approach

Comment: This one works for me. However, I believe there is a typo and it should be `startActivity(intents);`

Comment: @kimmi, how about for startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Catalogue")); delete activity stack except main activity

Answer (score 10):

when your going from one activity to other activity call finish();

do like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);

  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  startActivity(i);
  finish(); // to end the current activity
 }
```

call finish() after startactivity(...), so that A activity ll removed from the stack. when you press back button A activity ll be not there in stack.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE Please refer to the other answers, I cannot delete the answer because it is marked as accepted**

As per Our Discussion in Comments

Your Given Code is Fine !

**Q1. Why its Not Finishing All the Activities ?**

**Ans.** I think `All Activities Are Finished` `Except Activities` who have `Thread or AysncTask` running in Background or not Finished yet!

**Q2. How Can i Finish Them ?**

**Ans.** Make Sure your Thread Should be Finished ! or `You can Try Timeout etc` !

---

**Additional**

```
Pass String with Your Intent
```

for this Add Code

```
intent.putExtra("finishingallact", "yes");
```

Inside First Activity (Which is not to be Finished)

**Try by Making** `Object of Remaining Activities` to Finish Them !

So **Try code** :

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("finishingallact")!=null)
{
 if(getIntent().getStringExtra("finishingallact").toLowerCase().equals("yes"))
  {
    yourRemainingAct act1=new yourRemainingAct();
    act1.finish();
    // Try Same For ALl Remaining Activities 
  }
}
```

Comment: Note on thing more : it is not a good idea to kill Application in Android !

Comment: Hey @Tarsem I had used same as you tell. i have four activities. I am going like 1st activity -> 2nd activity ->third activity ->fourth activity, in fourth activity I come back to first activity and passed `intent.putExtra("finishingallact", "yes");` in fourth activity and in 1st activity i use your code if `(getIntent().getStringExtra("finishingallact")!=null)`  etc. but when I pressed back button it again goes to forth activity,three activity,two, one and after that it finish, but i had finished all the activities by making their objectss, Can you plz tell me where i am doing wrong, Thanks

Comment: @ErKimmiDhingra this approach is not good (performance wise), so try to use different approach for your app flow(fragments etc). Thanks

Comment: @Tarsem actully this project is more than half complete, & at this point I can't change it.Is there no any way so that we can finish all activities having asynctask too.

Comment: In my case, **its working using Static activity objects, instead of creating new object runtime.**

Answer (score 6):

**Try this it works fine with me**

```
// clear whole activity stack

    Intent intent = new Intent("clearStackActivity");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

// start your new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(OrderComplete.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE**

sorry I forget to give these lines. Put these line in onCreate() method of all Activities or if you have any base activity you can put it there , then no need to put in all activities.

```
private KillReceiver clearActivityStack;
clearActivityStack = new KillReceiver();
        registerReceiver(clearActivityStack, IntentFilter.create("clearStackActivity", "text/plain"));
```

**UPDATE**

So sorry forget one more thing to give put this class in your Base activity

```
private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

just remove every activity from stack except your first activity

```
youractivity.this.finish();
```

or you can use the Activity Single top.
for that you can use:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove all the Activities while opening new one, then do the following

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAcivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can Use :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove android:lanchMode="singleTop" from menifest and use setFlag `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Answer (score 0):

1.If we haven't the asynctask class or thread in our class then by simply

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

write this code,can easily remove all activities from stack

2.this can also be done by making launcher activity as **single task**
this can be done by changes in manifest file.
as

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

3.But if we have asynctask in our app and also use of thread then both above methods fail..

for that we have to finish activity one by one

for eg. **We have four activities A,B,C,D and each class has async task**

**and we have to go from A -> B-> C-> D**

**and from D We have again come back to **"A"*** and after pressing back button of device the app should be finish or can say exit*

For that we have to make static object of activities of all classes. Like

```
 **In class A**
     public static Avtivity mactivity;
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
            mactivity=this;
             }
```

**Do this in all classes B,C**

**And then in D**

By pressing a button 
finish the objects of all classes
Like

**mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            B mB=new B();
            mB.mactivity.finish();
                   //////do this for all class which are present in stack of activities
                            finish();
                            ////this will finish the D class and we reach at A class
                    }
                  });**
```

Thats solve...

I know its not a gud way but also not a bad one...And main thing is its working  :)