# Clear activity stack without using startActivity()

Tags: android, android-intent

Simple question: How can I clear `Activity` stack keeping current one?

I have a LoginActivity, HomeActivity and 100 more activities. I come to HomeActivity from 101 activities. I can clear activity stack

1. while calling `startActivity()` from those 101 activities using `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`
2. in the HomeActivity, only once

I want to do the 2nd. Is it possible? If yes, how? I want to clear activity stack to free resources.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18442510/5068931 have you try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` and
`android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your HomeActivity manifest tag.