# Android terminarte chid activies - like a pop to root

Tags: android, android-activity

How do go about doing a "pop to root" in Android.  I have and ActivityA which then starts ActivityB, which then starts ActivityC and finally starts ActivityD.  If the use uses the back button I want to go D->C->B->A as normal.  However if the user clicks on a button while in ActivityD, I want to destroy D, C, and B, and return to A.  I know this has to exist but can't find it.  Know this can be done with fragments, however because of the things that B, C an D do, they really need to stay as Activities.

Comment: `intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` Use these flags when you start activity A from D. It will clear the entire activity stack and bring activity A to front (if it exists, otherwise it creates activity A). I haven't tested it that's why it's in a comment instead of an answer. Let me know if it works. [should work]. And in the manifest you have to add this for activity A `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442328/how-to-finish-all-activities-except-the-first-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `startActivityForResult`.

When launching Activity B in Activity A, pass a code, do the same starting C in B and starting D in C.

When you fire the button in D, use `setResult(CODE)` and `finish()` to bounce back to `onActivityResult` in the C. Then catch that code there and fire the same `setResult` and `finish` there and so on until you get back to A.

There are a few ways this could be achieved but this should work for you.

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for!  Thanks!