# Clear ALL activities in back stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have this stack:

Login Activity -> Registration Activity

After a successful registration I call this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
i.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

And this finish my Registration activity BUT not my Login activity, so my stack stay like this:

Login Activity -> Home Activity

Any advice?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i ended up using this answer

[Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android)

And that do exactly what Im trying to do

Answer (score 1):

use this with intent in order to clear the backtrace activities

> **Java**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

> **Kotlin**

```
 var intent = Intent(this, [Your_activity]:class.java)
        intent.flags =  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear activities on the top of the stack ,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Still not finishing Login Activity

Comment: set your login activity android:noHistory="true" in the Android Manifest file or add the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY in your code to remove the  activity from the history stack.

Comment: But that make my login activity disappear when I go to register activity