# Why does Android start a new activity when my last activity calls finish()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I ran into a strange problem today : I have 3 activites : A, B and C.

A starts B then finishes. B starts C then finishes. C is the only one running. And guess what happens when I call `finish()` on C (I have an exit app button) ? **B is automatically created**

So I did something : on B's `onStart`, if a certain static flag is set up, B call `finish` on itself. And what happened ? **A was automatically created !**

I finally got around that by calling `finish()` on A's start too if the flag is set but this was somehow a nightmare.

NB : I was 100% sure that C was the only one running when I pressed the exit button, thanks to logs on `onDestroy()` etc. I was also sure that there was no thread / timer running in the background etc. The proof is that A was magically created when I forced killed B, but was not created before.

NB 2 : I know the exit button is not the good thing on Android but the app is running in a kiosk on a special hardware support and users don't have access to home button and back arrow etc, hence the exit button in the admin part of the app

Edit :

```
// B.java:

xxx.onClick() { startActivityForIntent(B.this, C.class); finish();}
```

// same for A.java with B

// C.java
   exit.onClick { finish(); }

A is the entry point activity of the app

Comment: Could you post some of the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @vipluv what parts specifically ? I would like to keep the question short

Comment: *that* is a good question, as well. :-P Maybe the part where B starts C and finishes, to begin with?

Comment: Is this not to do with the back stack preserving the previous activities?

Comment: I mean if you climb up a tree and cut the branch you are sitting on you will fall to the previous branch :P

Comment: @Duncan that shouldn't happen if he's calling finish() on the previous activities after starting the next one, right?

Comment: @vipluv I have edited. If you were expecting other code from reading my question could you please tell me what part was not clear (Im not a native English speaker) and often people ask me to put in more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
Apparently this behaviour is normal: Android wakes up the previous activity on the activity stack if you try to exit using finish(); this is because the OS wants your application to survive unexpected situations like phone-calls interrupting the user.

See this answer: [Finish all previous activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities).

Try adding `android:noHistory="true"` for all your activities in their xml files.

That, or try some of the methods mentioned in the answer above.