# How to clear all previous activities?

Tags: android

I have created an android app with 5 activities .i.e **1.java,2.java,3.java,4.java,5.java**. and Splash also there.

I have used intents to move from one activity to another.
I have defined few operations on buttons i.e changing the background image of that button and assigning values to strings in that activities.

I used `moveTaskToBack()` method on clicking back button from all my java files.

and i have kept  `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`  in manifest file.

from 5.java I have to move to Splash page and have to restart whole app ..

when  i have moved from Splash to 1.java page it is showing previously entered details ..

my problem is how to clear all the previously entered details in 1.java page,2.java page,3.java page,4,java page,5.java page.

please give answer...thank uu...

Comment: when you are using back button java 5 to 4 or Java 4 to 3 use finish();

Comment: call finish(); when you call new Intent;

Comment: For which API level?

Maybe if 11+ this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities

Comment: thanking u for answering..

Comment: I have called finish(); from all activities..But when i pressed back button from 4.java it have show the previously entered details in 3,java like wise from 2.java,3.java also..

Comment: I have to clear after restarting from Splash to 1.java and so on

Comment: For that there are 2 approach 1 is start next activity using startactivityforresult and resultcode on onActivityresult and 2 is make static flag and check that flag on each activity and then finish activity

Comment: please tell me in detail

Comment: I have found the answer that just creating   public static Activity fa; outside onCreate and in onCreate(){fa=this;} in all activities and finishing 1.fa.finish();2.fa.finish();3.fa.finish();4.fa.finish();  in 5.java onCreate.

Answer (score 2):

Just call  `finish()` before you starting the another `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are moving from java5 class to Splash Screen.

You need to clear the previously opened activities like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Java5Class.this, SplashScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this, it will work while pressing backbutton

```
   @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
            {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), previousActivvty.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

This will clear all the activities on top of home.

Answer (score 1):

after starting new activity, finish the activity you want to destroy.

```
StartActivity(new Intent(this,Second.class));
finish();
```