# Contingent PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am using an `AlarmManager` to schedule various `Notification`s to the user. It all works well, but I would like to allow the user to tap on the notification and be taken directly to the app. Normally that is easy enough, but in my situation, it's a little more difficult.

Since these notifications will appear at a point in the future (a few days, typically), I do not have any way of knowing whether my app will be active when the notification is posted and when the user taps on it. If the app is active, I want the `PendingIntent` to take the user to an activity called `PostAuthenticationActivity`). But if the app is not active, I need the app to go through its usual startup and login routine, which is handled from an activity called `SplashScreenActivity`. I do not know how to make this `PendingIntent` smart enough to make this determination.

```
private Notification getNotification(String title) {

        Intent resultIntent;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {

            // either these lines works on it's own, if I know whether the state of the app
            // how can I build in logic to make this decision dynammically?

            if (appIsRunning)  //pseudocode
                resultIntent = new Intent(this.context, PostAuthenticationActivity.class);
            else
                resultIntent = new Intent(this.context, SplashScreenActivity.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this.context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText("Your have a group workout starting in one hour.");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.we_run_single);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            return builder.build();

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the user to `PostAuthenticationActivity` by default, inside of this activity you could check whether authentication is required or not. If auth is required then start your `SplashScreenActivity` and finish all others.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreenActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

[How to start new activity and clear all others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)