# How to close all open Activities and open a new one from a Java Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have created a class that is extending from `CountDownTimer`, It has a a method `onFinish()` which calls when `timer` expires.

There are 6 Activities, user can be in any `activity` when timer expires,  So in `CounterTimer`when  `Finish()` method calls , i need to show an `Alert Message` to the user,along with i need to redirect user to `Login` page.

Things getting confusing, as i cannot call `Intent class` in the `Normal Class`, I can also not pass the `context`, as user can be in any activity.

I have written following code, but its not helping out.

I am using context here, but its giving error message on passing `context` to `Intent`

```
public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer implements ITMServiceEvent {

  @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if(sql_code.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            String resultCode = command1.getString("result");
            context.startActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            }
```

Calling Timer at the Start of Wizard, in a Fragment

```
CounterClass counterClass= new CounterClass(180000,1000);
counterClass.setTextView(tvTimer);
counterClass.start();
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6330456/5296734) out, it may help you.

Comment: @nick7291: Thanks, let me try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finish all previous activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of your question, first is how you can clean up the Activity stack and start a new Activity on Top of them, I suppose this would be the LoginActivity in your case.

To do this, you need to set the Flag of your LoginActivity Intent when you want to start it,

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

And the second part is, you want to be able to finish the current activity after showing a dialog to the user. I assume your Timer is a Service Class, which runs in the background. The way to tell your current activity that the Time is Up ! is to send a Broadcast Message. Preferably, [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) can help you out. You can have a BaseActivity class where all of your 6 Activities can be extended from it and you can register/unregister `LocalBroadcastManager` to/from those activities in the `BaseActivity` class (register in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause`). After you register them you just need to implement and handle the `onReceive` method where you can show a dialog and start the `LoginActivity` after finishing the current one.