# Finish all activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I do start an activity A using intent from within a`PreferenceScreen`. What I do want to do is pretty simple. Depending on some actions the user may take I want to finish all previous activities and start the LoginActivity. Something like restarting the whole application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finish all previous activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flag in intent to clear all the activities in the stack

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi @Siva. You saved my day. You definitely deserve a hug.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `finishAffinity()` after `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use finishAffinity() after startActivity()