# How can I get back to start page by clicking the image in navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I´ve set up an android app with navigation drawer activity. There is an image of the activity by default and I want to go back to start page by clicking it.
How can I do that?

> MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Dialog myDialog;
    NodemcuListFragment nodemcuListFragment;
    ConstraintLayout content;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        content = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        nodemcuListFragment = (NodemcuListFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this,NodemcuListFragment.class.getName(),null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.home){
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_sensors) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout, nodemcuListFragment).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
            GmapFragment gmapFragment = new GmapFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout,gmapFragment).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            // Activity which shows settings
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contactUs) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Team 1337"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ubiquitous Project" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `MainActivity` in the method `onNavigationItemSelected` I can switch in the menu, but if I address their the "androidImg" it doesn´t react...

Comment: Would you please provide the code what you are tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finish all previous activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I paste the code from my MainActivity.

Comment: Can nobody help me?