# Destroy activity when creating the same activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities A and B, A is defined as "singletask" on the manifest launch mode, as it should be and i cannot change this. A launches activity B, then when B clicks the back button i want to launch activity A again, but i want to destroy the previous activity, and create a new instance of A. right now the following code is not working. It just takes me back to the old A activity.

```xml
<activity
            android:name="A"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

```java
 public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,A.class);
        intent.putExtra("newextra1","newextra1");
        intent.putExtra("newextra2","newextra2");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25016158/966550

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` in Activity A **after** you call the intent for Activity B. It will be executed even if another Intent is started before calling finish().

You are calling `finish()` in Activity B but not Activity A.

if you want the old activity in some cases and new in some, then just pass a flag(boolean) in intent that tells the activity to restart or not. Then if the flag is yes you do

```
finish(); 
startActivity(getIntent());
```

in Activity A.

Comment: Yeah the thing is that B will not always start from A, it can start from some other activity C, in that case i still want to go back to A and kill it

Comment: @rickyl22 if you finish A after calling *any* intent, it will work for your scenario. So call finish after intent for C as well.

Comment: @rickyl22 or if you want the old activity in some cases and new in some, then just pass a flag(boolean) in intent that tells the activity to restart or not. Then if the flag is yes you do `finish();
startActivity(getIntent());` in Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```